# My codeblocks ide is not working.Showing blank page?

Tags: codeblocks

[Here is the blank page, when I open my codeBlocks ide](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H924i.jpg)
Actually, when I open my ide ,there are all projects that I did before. When I cross off down all of these, then there is a blank page. I uninstalled it and then installed it again .But there is same problem.When I run a 20 lines code it is taking more time(approx 30 minutes or more or is not working). Actually what problem is going on this ide ,I  am not understanding.Please help

Comment: Please see the image before giving me suggestion

Answer (score 0):

To restore the default layout, try this (from menu): View -> Perspective -> C::B default